# Need an explanation about evaluating a given expression

Tags: c, arithmetic-expressions

The expression is as follows

```
(ux-uy) == -(unsigned) (y-x)
```

where `x` and `y` are random integers and `ux` and `uy` are declared and defined as follows

```
unsigned ux = (unsigned) x;
unsigned uy = (unsigned) y;
```

I tested the expression in c with various numbers and it was correct
but I cant prove why it is correct. please explain.

Comment: Whether `signed` or not is `ux - uy == -(uy - ux)` or not? You think of it as a mathematical problem, and you shall see what is going on.

Comment: do a case by case analysis, i.e., when x greater than y by n, y greater than x by n, equal.

Comment: I am confused about the - sign in front of RHS. what exactly does it do ?

Comment: @user1335175: The `-` sign in front of the cast means that the result is negated, and then converted back to an `(unsigned int)` again (because the LHS of the equality is an `unsigned int`) before the comparison is done.

Answer (score 2):

`y-x` --> undefined behavior should the `int` subtraction overflow.

So the equality `(ux-uy) == -(unsigned) (y-x)` fails, in general.